# Anyone knows what type of conduit/duct/hose this is?

Tags: conduit, ducts, hose

I have been looking everywhere for this hose. I don't know what it's called because it's very uncommon in our country.

Tried searching for semi-rigid duct but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

You can see how it works here:
https://youtu.be/1oUuihNseb0?t=102

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is being used as a floor vacuum hose.

Comment: I've seen lamps made with that kind of flexible tube called "gooseneck" lamps. Try web-searching for "gooseneck tubing".

Comment: Try "flexible plastic duct". The word "duct" may get you 6" diameter or larger, but "plastic" may limit it to something like this.

Comment: I tried a Google Images search using your photo.  The best I got was a Chinese washing machine.

Comment: Still couldn't find it. Man what is this thing lol.